# Error on class having definiton errors

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
InitializeComponent();

var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Rootobject>("container");
var res = collection.Aggregate().Group(x => x._event.NodeId,  x => new { Name = x.Key, WTs = x.Select(r => r._event.WT).ToList() }).ToList();

cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
{
    new LineSeries
    {
        Title = res["event"]["NodeId"] ,
        Values = new ChartValues<double> {4.0, 3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 3.8, 3.8, 3.75}
    },
}
```

The code above , i am trying to use my mongodb for my graphs input . But first i need to be able to query from MongoDB , i have come up with a var record but the 'NodeId' still has errors. it has `Event[] does not contain a definition for 'NodeID' and no extension method 'NodeId' accepting a first argument of type Event[]`. Below are my public classes

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public Header[] header { get; set; }
    public Event[] _event { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please don't vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
.Group(x => x._event.NodeId
```

Your `_event` property is of type `Event[]`, which is an array of `Event`. You can get one *item* of your array and access the `NodeId` property (e.g. the from the first element with `_event[0].NodeId`, which will work if this element exists), but not from the array *itself*.

I can not tell you with what you should replace this part with, because that depends entirely on what you want to achieve.